# Что лучше использовать null или unset

Tags: php

Я теперь в замешательстве и не понимаю что лучше использовать

`$a = null;`

или

`unset($a);`

Расскажите подробнее чем та или иная конструкция отличается

Comment: Странно это сравнивать, ведь присвоение `null` говорит: "Чувак, переменная пуста!", тогда как `unset` намекает: "Обкурился штоле? Такой переменной нет.".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Между двумя этими операциями имеется разница

```
<?php
$fst = 'hello';
$snd = 'world';
$fst = null;
unset($snd);

echo $fst; // null
echo $snd; // Notice: Undefined variable: snd
```

Присваивая переменной `null`, в таблице символов вашего скрипта остается переменная со значением `null`. Удаляя переменную при помощи конструкции `unset()` вы удаляете ее из таблицы символов.

Правильно удалять переменную `unset()`. Присвоением `null` вы не удаляете переменную, а присваиваете ей значение `null` - да `isset()` покажет `false`, но переменная существует. Более того, вы найдете еще несколько тонких моментов в случае переменных объектов и элементов массива. `unset()` удалит и значение и переменную из таблицы символов. Хотите удалить переменную - удаляйте `unset()`.

Comment: я слышал что unset срабатывает когда приходит сборщик мусора php (то есть не сразу, не при вызове unset), а вот null'ом можно сразу зачистить переменную

Comment: Врать не буду, не исследовал исходники на эту тему, однако разумно было бы просто занулять ссылку на выделенный объект при присвоении переменной null и собирать его потом штатно тем же сборщиком мусора. Дорогова-то зачищать каждую переменную в отдельности, если не позднее, чем через несколько секунд можно будет всю кучу скопом освободить (возможно даже не запуская сборщик).

Comment: да вот кстати разница будет только при случае если когда будет присвоение по ссылке `$a = "10"; $b = &$a; $a = null;` - как итог все в `null` а если применить вместо `null, unset($a)`, то переменная `$b` будет существовать со значением 10...просто я уже не знаю как правильно...запутался окончательно, кто-нибудь бы разъяснил все по полочкам, был бы благодарен

Comment: @MaximPro Правильно удалять переменную unset(). В случае с ссылкой все верно, вместо null вы можете подставить значение 10 и получите то же результат и $a, и $b получат одно и тоже значение. Присвоением null вы не удаляете переменную, а присваиваете ей значение null - да isset() покажет false, но переменная существует. Более того, вы найдете еще несколько тонких моментов в случае переменных объектов и элементов массива. unset() удалит и значение и переменную из таблицы символов. Хотите удалить переменную - удаляйте unset().

Comment: хмм...ладно...буду делать как вы сказали